# How to select min datediff value on a record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got a database of contacts that have registered to attend a range of events. The database also contains a table of address information. Frequently, individual contacts have multiple address records.

I need a query that returns an individual's event booking, along with the postcode from their most recent address record (relative to the date of the event).

I'm trying to use min(DATEDIFF) in the query below, but although it's correctly calculating the date difference between the event booking and the address record creation, the query's still returning duplicate results where an individual has more than one address record.

Appreciate if anyone can please advise where I'm going wrong in the query below, or advise on a better way to obtain the result:

```
SELECT ep.EVENTPLACENO, ad.POSTCODE, min(DATEDIFF(dd,ep.CREATIONDATE,ad.CREATIONDATE)) as datediff
FROM EVENTPLACE as ep
LEFT OUTER JOIN EVENTMODULE as em ON em.EVENTMODULENO=ep.EVENTMODULENO
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS as ad ON ad.CONTACTNO=ep.CONTACTNO
WHERE em.EVENTMODULENO = '1111111-2222222-3333333-4444444'
GROUP BY ep.EVENTPLACENO, ad.POSTCODE
```

Comment: add ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ep.EVENTPLACENO, ad.POSTCODE ORDER BY DATEDIFF(dd,ep.CREATIONDATE,ad.CREATIONDATE)) as rown    then query the query as a derived query, selecting rown=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT ep.EVENTPLACENO, ad.POSTCODE, min(ad.CREATIONDATE) as datediff 
FROM EVENTPLACE as ep
LEFT OUTER JOIN EVENTMODULE as em ON em.EVENTMODULENO=ep.EVENTMODULENO
 OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *  FROM ADDRESS ad2 WHERE  ad2.CONTACTNO=ep.CONTACTNO ORDER BY DATEDIFF(dd,ep.CREATIONDATE,ad2.CREATIONDATE)) AD
WHERE em.EVENTMODULENO = '1111111-2222222-3333333-4444444'
GROUP BY ep.EVENTPLACENO, ad.POSTCODE
```

you can use OUTER APPLY to LEFT JOIN to the TOP 1 of a sub query - the sub query then exists for the LEFT row that you are joining to the sub query - where the sub query is a TOP 1, it will join 1 to 1 (or 1 to null if no row)

Comment: Andrew - this works great. I've never used OUTER APPLY before. Many thanks for your help.